# LibXML2 iOS 7 XCode Compiler Error

Tags: ios7, xcode5, libxml2

I have used libxml2 on previous projects.

However I am now getting this error when compiling my latest project:

> Lexical or Preprocessor issue 'tree.h' file not found

Yes, I have scoured and searched for answers, all which suggest the following:

- Adding variations (have tried them all) of '"${SDK_DIR}"/usr/include/libxml2' to your Header Search Path. Set Always Search to YES.
- Adding libxml2.dylib to your build phases
- Adding -lxml2 to Other Linker Flags

I have been adding the above to both my Target and Project settings. I've tried all variations for the Header Search Path. I have added both libxml2.dylib / libxml2.2.dylib separately to my build phases.

I always Clean/Build also, however nothing seems to be working.

I'm getting really fed up at this stage. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

Originally I had downloaded the 'TouchXML' files from GitHub. Touch XML is what I'm using to parse data for my app.

After downloading these files from a different source, copying them over to my XCode project, and removing the files from GitHub, I was able to avoid the above LibXML2 errors.

I did however need to add '-fno-objc-arc' flags on all of the TouchXML '.m' files, under Build Phases, as they weren't compatible with ARC.